# How to hidden the Office 2010 Application using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In the past, if we want to running office 2003,2007 application in the background, we can set  the value of  "Visible" property  to $False. But we couldn't do same action in office 2010, if I set the value to $fasle or "msoFalse", it'll get the error message, something like:

===========================

Exception setting "Visible": "Application (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Hiding the application window is not

allowed."

At line:1 char:1

- $app.Visible="msoFalse"

Or

Exception setting "Visible": "Cannot convert value "False" to type "Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState". Error:

"Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState'.""

=============================

If I set the value of "Visible" to "msoTrue", it works fine and no error will happen.

Does anyone have any ideas what would cause this? And how to enable office 2010 application running in the background?

by the way, i using same action on word,excel 2010 no error will happen, and it works good. But only running on powerpoint 2010, i got the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I can do the same with office 2010. For example, showing and hiding Word:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible=$true
$word.Visible=$false
```

Comment: Yeah, I can show the window but I can't hide it, $pp.Visible=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
Exception setting "Visible": "Application (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Hiding the application window is not allowed."

Comment: Word and PPT don't use the same type of requests....

Comment: Sorry I downvoted, but truly question doesn't specify, likely OP was working w/ PPT not Doc.

Answer (score 1):

CB. was correct in that you could use MsoTriState but it's options are not so obvious from the powershell bindings. You can review the definition of the Open command:

```
PS C:\Users\jidar\Documents> $doc.Presentations.Open

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
Presentation Open (string, MsoTriState, MsoTriState, MsoTriState)
```

Attempting to follow the above definition, I was able to use the following:

```
$doc.Presentations.Open($item, [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse)
```

I didn't dig into which msoFalse was required or not, so it may require some verification.

Edit: Forgot to mention, this was tested on Office 2016 (YMMV on other versions)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [MsoTriState enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.msotristate.aspx):

```
$app.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
```

or

```
$app.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Using $app.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
still get error message.

Comment: Try give some hints from here: http://naimishpandya.wordpress.com/category/power-point-office-automation/  Sorry, but I can't convert and test  it now for powershell, but I believe it can works.

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Try this: http://naimishpandya.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/hide-power-point-application-window-in-net-office-automation/